# Accessing default dict changes in operator

Tags: python

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> x = defaultdict(int) 
>>> x[1] =99
>>> 1 in x  
True
>>> 2 in x
False
>>> x[2]
0
>>> 2 in x
True
```

is it possible to access default dict without changing how the in operator function?

Comment: Could you provide what do you want, or what does your expected output look like?

Comment: i want `2 in x` on the last line to be false

Comment: Why are you using a `defaultdict` if you don't want this behaviour? This is basically the only difference between a `defaultdict` and a regular `dict`.

Comment: two different sections of the code uses this default dict. One for adding values and the other for accessing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use get function

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> x = defaultdict(int)
>>> x[1]=99
>>> 2 in x
False
>>> x.get(2)
>>> x.get(2,False)
False
>>> 2 in x
False
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own class and modify the `__missing__` method.
Here you want to keep all the functionalities of defaultdict but don't want to keep the key if it was missing so you can just delete it after returning the result.

```
from collections import defaultdict
class myDefDict(defaultdict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        result = super().__missing__(key)
        del self[key]
        return result
```

Then to test it:

```
>>> x = myDefDict(int)
>>> x[1] = 99
>>> 1 in x  
True
>>> 2 in x
False
>>> x[2]
0
>>> 2 in x
False
```